# Is it possible to lock certain words from moving in a <p>

Tags: html, css

```
<p>Hello I'm a potato and i like to eat fishes</p>
```

Let's say that the code above displays like this :

Hello I'm a potato
and I like to eat fishes

When I resize it may look like

Hello I'm a
potato and I like
to eat fishes

What I'd like is that the "Hello" is always right above the "and" even when resizing.

meaning that the above example would display:

Hello I'm a potato
and I like
to eat fishes

Is it possible without using `<br>` ?

Comment: You could add `<br>` before the "and" and set a `min-width` for your `<p>`

Comment: add `<br>` with css style `overflow: auto;` but text will be scrollable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the text in spans and make them display block:

```css
span {
  display:block;      /* makes each span have it's own line */
  white-space:nowrap; /* will keep all the spans on their own line */
}
```

```html
<p><span>Hello i'm a potato</span> <span>and i like to</span> <span>eat fishes</span></p>
```